# program booms when assign a 3D array which is dynamically allocated

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I wrote some codes about dynamically allocating 3D arrays on codeblocks with GCC compiler.

Version1:

```
void*** alloc3(int n_s, int n_row, int n_col, int size)
{
 void*** p=(void***)malloc(n_s*sizeof(void**));
 int i,j,k;
 if (p==NULL) return NULL;
 for(i=0;i<n_s;i++){
 p[i] = (void**)malloc(n_row*sizeof(void*));
 for(j=0;j<n_row;j++)
   {
    p[i][j]=(char*)malloc(n_col*size);
    if(p[i][j]==NULL) {free(p[0]);free(p);return NULL; }
   }
  }
 return p;
}
```

Version2:

```
void*** alloc3 (int n1, int n2, int n3, int size)
{
int i3,i2;
void ***p;

if ((p=(void***)malloc(n3*sizeof(void**)))==NULL)
        return NULL;
if ((p[0]=(void**)malloc(n3*n2*sizeof(void*)))==NULL) {
        free(p);
        return NULL;
  }
if ((p[0][0]=(void*)malloc(n3*n2*n1*size))==NULL) {
        free(p[0]);
        free(p);
        return NULL;
  }

for (i3=0; i3<n3; i3++) {
        p[i3] = p[0]+n2*i3;
        for (i2=0; i2<n2; i2++)
                p[i3][i2] = (char*)p[0][0]+size*n1*(i2+n2*i3);
  }
return p;
}
```

I tested these codes.

```
double*** B= (double*** )alloc3(n_row,n_col,n_s,sizeof(double));
for(int i=0;i<n_s;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<n_row;j++)
  {
    for(int k=0;k<n_col;k++)
    {
        printf("(%d,%d,%d)\t",i,j,k);
        B[i][j][k] = 1.0;
    }printf("\n");
}printf("----------\n");
}
```

There was a debug tips/error:

[image]

but if i cut off the line `B[i][j][k] = 1.0;`, every thing is ok. I cannot figure out what is wrong with this stuff. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: This is clearly C, not C++. Also,`free(p[0]); free(p);` will leak memory.

Comment: [Not replicable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0999d26ba886ec13)

Comment: version 2 is bogus, you never allocate `p[1]` etc.

Comment: version 1 should work if there are no allocation failures (the error checking and recovery code is very bad)

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which one failed, but it doesn't really matter as both are incorrect.

In C you cannot convert a type void** or type void*** to type double** or type double*** without causing undefined behavior. Both function in your example do this.

It would be very inconvenient and probably not really possible to correctly write a generic function that allocates memory like you imagine.

There is a better way, use pointers to variable lenght arrays:

```
double (*d)[y][x] = malloc( z * y * x * sizeof( double ) );
d[z-1][y-1][x-1] = 123.45;
```

You only need to call free once:

```
free( d );
```

Comment: It is greatly usefull ! Thanks a lot.